# is a big functions php file a concern?

Tags: php, performance, function

I'm developing a web application and I'm using a file called functions.php in which I stored all the functions related to my application, currently the file has about 1500 lines of code with over 30 functions.

I was wondering if it is a problem, could it slow down the process when calling functions? Should I make other files to move some of the functions there?

Comment: You could make it a class, that might make it run a bit smoother.

Comment: @Rune While I'm a supporter of OOP - could you add an explanation as to why/how a class with 1500+ lines and 30+ functions would be smoother than a simple file with them all as I'm not really seeing it.

Comment: @newfurniturey Well ok, maybe not exactly smoother, but it can be more handy and the code should be better readable too. It's mostly what you prefer I guess.

Comment: A bit off-topic to discuss the merits of OOP vs. Procedural in this question, since without seeing the code or what it does, there's no real telling what the better answer is.

Comment: I think it's about what you prefer most, if you are an OOP fan then you will go for it, myself I'm not, So I always go for OOP, I thought that OOP was slower btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, the number of lines in the .php script isn't going to affect the speed of the program nearly as much as the code itself.  If execution time is your number one concern, then optimizing your code should be your number one priority.  Start with the functions that are called the most, and make sure the code there is as tight as possible.

Splitting the functions up into different files would technically make the script *slower* since the interpreter would have to do disk I/O to parse the files.  But the speed hit would be infinitesimal, so I'd argue that splitting them up might *save* time in the long run since it'll be easier to debug and optimize if you're not always staring down a huge file with 30 functions in it.

Finally, if you *do* have to use a bunch of huge .php files in your app, you might want to look into using something like [Zend](http://www.zend.com/en/) that will compile your scripts on the server.

Comment: Thank you , I guess this is the most complete answer !

Comment: @Scott, "technically" and "infinitesimal" are not the correct adjectives.  Yes this would be the case on a dedicated LAMP+APC/Xcache VM or system where the scripts would be ACP (or VFAT) cached, but in a shared hosting environment each extra script file will generate perhaps an average of 10+ mS of off-server I/O.  These can add up.

Answer (score 2):

If you only use one or two functions per page, would it be faster to split them up into separate files and only include the ones you need?  Yes, because PHP needs to read through the whole file to include it.  Will it make a noticeable enough difference that it's worth splitting the file?  In most cases the answer's probably no.

Comment: So you advise me to just keep my file?

Comment: You have to decide based on your site and how much you think it will affect performance.  For a 1500 line file it's probably fine to keep it in one.  If the file were 15000 lines it might be a different story.

Comment: Thank you , that's helping :)