# wordpress shortcode just for one page

Tags: php, wordpress-shortcode

I wrote a shortcode that is used for displaying data and it is used just in one page (ie: PAGEX using *full-width-page-template.php*). The shortcode function is very huge.

```
function rj_mysh_shortcode() {
   // Lots of lines of business logic
}
add_shortcode('rj_mysh', 'rj_mysh_shortcode');
```

Every time a webpage is called I think functions.php is called and parsed by PHP. I'm looking for a solution in order to avoid to spend time in parsing something not useful.

I thought that I can create a template TEMPLATE_PAGEX and move the function there.

```
TEMPLATE_PAGEX.php:
<?php
    function rj_mysh_shortcode_template() {
       // Lots of lines of business logic
    }

include(locate_template('full-width-page-template.php'));
?>
```

At the end the shortcode is:

```
function rj_mysh_shortcode() {
   return rj_mysh_shortcode_template()
}
add_shortcode('rj_mysh', 'rj_mysh_shortcode');
```

Is this the right solution?

Rr

Comment: Why not leave the function in functions.php (or another file that is included in functions.php) and check if you are on the page you want it to run on within the function, and if not, don't run it?

Comment: Check what page you are on: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ ... is_page($pageID)

Comment: @Dammeul: I think that is something related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919843/is-a-big-functions-php-file-a-concern. What is your idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always check what page you are on: [developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page) ... `is_page($pageID)` ... and only run the code if on that page.

```
function rj_mysh_shortcode() {
    if(is_page($pageID)) {
      // Lots of lines of business logic
    }
}
add_shortcode('rj_mysh', 'rj_mysh_shortcode');
```

or just remove the need for a `shortcode`, and just run the logic/code etc. directly from `functions.php` but doing the same page check so it only gets ran on that specific page.

Comment: Let's suppose that business logic is 1000 rows. With your solution when I display the homepage PHP must parse rj_mysh_shortcode even if it will never executed. Now, my dubt is: the parsing time can slow down my website or it is a paranoia? (I'm using W3 Total Cache)

Comment: It won't run it if you're on the homepage, unless the home page is the ID that you use in the is_page() function.  If it isn't, on the home page it will return false, and therefore not run any of your code..?

Comment: Thats's true... but PHP parsed a huge functions.php. Parsing time will be a problem or the difference will be infinitesimal...

Comment: If you have an issue with parsing time of a PHP file with only a 1000 lines then you should look at optimising your code.  You could have this function in a separate file all together, and include it in your functions PHP for ease of reading and such, but I wouldn't stress over including it as long as you check for the page and don't run it if not on that page.

Comment: You could always add it to a seperate file, and include that file in your theme template file too and avoid using the shortcode / any WP functionality, though I do think a shortcode is overkill if you're using this function in just one place, and can do it all through code.

Comment: It'll be a huge difference if checking for the page on any page other than the one you want it to run, as the only overhead will be the is_page() function.

Comment: Ok. At the moment I added the function rj_mysh_shortcode in the page template (as I mentioned befire) and I declared in functions.php add_shortcode('rj_mysh', 'rj_mysh_shortcode');

Comment: Definitely a way to do it, though I'm not sure on the overhead of registering the shortcode etc etc. compared to simply writing clean PHP code that instruction your code not to run unless on a specific page.

Comment: I want to use shortcode beacuse they are easy to maintain... With my solution functions.php has -1000 rows and +1 small shortcode..

Comment: Fair enough, but using a short code over pure code won't be great for performance if you get in the habit doing that for code that only needs to be used once

Comment: and using a separate file for your big function and including that in functions.php would also be easy to maintain without the added overhead of a shortcode.